# Java, how to download videos from youtube, vget alternative?

Tags: java, youtube, download

I have tried to use the vGet library, but it returns the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.github.axet.wget.info.ex.DownloadRetry: no video with required quality found
    at com.github.axet.vget.info.VGetParser.getVideo(VGetParser.java:38)
    at com.github.axet.vget.info.YouTubeParser.extract(YouTubeParser.java:388)
    at com.github.axet.vget.info.VGetParser.extract(VGetParser.java:15)
    at com.github.axet.vget.info.VideoInfo.extract(VideoInfo.java:100)
    at com.github.axet.vget.VGet.download(VGet.java:224)
    at com.github.axet.vget.VGet.download(VGet.java:68)
    at Test.main(Test.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Is there any other library or any kind of solution exists to download videos from youtube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTube is changing it's way of video management all the time, while vGet is not updated so often, so that's why vGet can NOT download videos from Youtube.